# What is the difference between willRotateToInterfaceOrientation and deviceOrientationDidChange?

Tags: ios, orientation

In the context of detecting and reacting to an orientation change, I've seen two approaches: implementing `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` or asking the view to begin emitting relevant notifications (`deviceOrientationDidChange`).

When is the latter intended to be used? What would the advantage be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method is part of [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willRotateToInterfaceOrientation%3aduration%3a). If you've derived from a UIViewController you only need to override this method to be informed about orientation changes.

However, if you're in some other class and want to be informed about orientation changes then you need to register for the [UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW38).

Answer (score 1):

methods that begin with "will" are triggered before action is executed, method that begin with "did" after. This is the approach of the whole framework! When to use one of the two depends on your needs